# What's the cost of running S3 API ListObjectV2 with delimiter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Let's say I have a huge S3 bucket with billions of files, and these files are organized in an hierarchical fashion, like you would have in a standard file system. My concern is with `ls` operations performance in S3, for example the one below that would be equivalent to `ls /`.

```
$ aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket my-huge-bucket --delimiter /
{
    "CommonPrefixes": [
        {
            "Prefix": "dir1/"
        },
        {
            "Prefix": "dir2/"
        }
    ],
    "RequestCharged": null
}
```

In a file system if I want to list all directores under the root (`ls /`), I know this will list only for the children inodes linked to the root inode and not scan all objects in the file system to respond this operation.

Now in S3, because it does not have the same idea of inodes as you have in a standard FS, and in fact, all objects are mapped by keys that happen to allow `/` in the name to create a "virtual" idea of directories, I'm concerned with the performance of such operation. Will S3 behind the scenes scan through all object keys in the bucket to compute what would be the next directories under what you are listing from (e.g. root /) or will it be smart enough to only consider files with different prefixes starting from the root?

Comment: Amazon does not document the inner workings of S3 to such a degree one can answer this question.  That said, they [don't call out](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/optimizing-performance-guidelines.html) large number of objects as a problem listing prefixes, and anecdotally, listing the "root directory" and showing a few hundred objects and common prefixes takes the same time on a bucket with a total of thousands of objects as one with around a hundred million objects.

Comment: I think the object list is probably some sort of sorted collection that would allow listing (including rolling up a prefix) to be reasonably efficient with a ton of objects. Specifically, custom delimiters that you can specify per call would be pretty hard to do well otherwise. Given the lack of performance horror stories or warnings from Amazon about it, I would tend to think it's efficient.